# running multiple spark applications in parallel

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop-yarn

I'm running a YARN + spark 2.4.5 cluster. I'm running the jobs using a docker as a yarn client mode.
I configured the master and the docker client as follows:

**yarn-site.xml**

```
<property>
    <name>yarn.resourcemanager.scheduler.class</name>
    <value>org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.scheduler.fair.FairScheduler</value>
  </property>
 <property>
    <name>yarn.scheduler.fair.preemption</name>
    <value>true</value>
  </property>


  <property>
    <name>yarn.scheduler.fair.assignmultiple</name>
    <value>true</value>
  </property>
```

**fairscheduler.xml:**

```
<allocations>
  <pool name="default">
    <schedulingMode>FAIR</schedulingMode>
    <maxRunningApps>2</maxRunningApps>
    <fairSharePreemptionThreshold>0.6</fairSharePreemptionThreshold>
    <fairSharePreemptionTimeout>1</fairSharePreemptionTimeout>
    <weight>2</weight>
    <minShare>2</minShare>
  </pool>

  <pool name="today">
    <schedulingMode>FAIR</schedulingMode>
    <maxRunningApps>2</maxRunningApps>
    <fairSharePreemptionThreshold>0.6</fairSharePreemptionThreshold>
    <fairSharePreemptionTimeout>1</fairSharePreemptionTimeout>
    <weight>2</weight>
    <minShare>2</minShare>
  </pool>

  <pool name="yesterday">
    <schedulingMode>FAIR</schedulingMode>
    <maxRunningApps>2</maxRunningApps>
    <weight>1</weight>
    <fairSharePreemptionThreshold>0.4</fairSharePreemptionThreshold>
    <fairSharePreemptionTimeout>1</fairSharePreemptionTimeout>
    <minShare>2</minShare>
  </pool>
</allocations>
```

Now, I lunch two spark apps in two different containers. the first and then the second after a minute or two:

```
spark-submit --deploy-mode client --name job1 --queue today --py-files gs://babadod/spark.zip gs://babadod/spark/main.py --job job1 --job-args date=2020-04-02

spark-submit --deploy-mode client --name job2 --queue yesterday --py-files gs:/babadod/spark.zip gs://babadod/spark/main.py --job job2 --job-args date=2020-04-01
```

The output start on each of them:

```
20/04/02 13:52:08 INFO SparkUI: Bound SparkUI to 0.0.0.0, and started at http://namenode:4040
20/04/02 13:52:08 INFO FairSchedulableBuilder: Creating Fair Scheduler pools from /opt/spark/conf/fairscheduler.xml
20/04/02 13:52:09 INFO FairSchedulableBuilder: Created pool: default, schedulingMode: FAIR, minShare: 2, weight: 2
20/04/02 13:52:09 INFO FairSchedulableBuilder: Created pool: today, schedulingMode: FAIR, minShare: 2, weight: 2
20/04/02 13:52:09 INFO FairSchedulableBuilder: Created pool: yesterday, schedulingMode: FAIR, minShare: 2, weight: 1
20/04/02 13:52:09 INFO Utils: Using initial executors = 0, max of spark.dynamicAllocation.initialExecutors, spark.dynamicAllocation.minExecutors and spark.executor.instances
20/04/02 13:52:09 INFO RMProxy: Connecting to ResourceManager at namenode/10.128.15.208:8032
20/04/02 13:52:09 INFO Client: Requesting a new application from cluster with 2 NodeManagers
```

The first app is taking all the available resource and the second starts after the first finishes.
What do I miss?
Thanks

---

**EDIT**

**spark-defaults.conf:**

```
spark.master yarn;
spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled true;
spark.shuffle.service.enabled true;
spark.yarn.shuffle.stopOnFailure false;
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't find a source, but as I recall, spark needs to be in dynamic resource allocation mode to allow yarn to kill executors when needed.

try setting enabling it with the settings from here: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html#dynamic-allocation

(you will need to setup a shuffle service as well: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/running-on-yarn.html#configuring-the-external-shuffle-service)

Comment: Already doing this: this is my spark-defaults.conf
spark.master yarn;spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled true;spark.shuffle.service.enabled true;
spark.yarn.shuffle.stopOnFailure false